# How to properly use redux with react-native navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have been trying to do a setup using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md) and followed the steps. Then tried to follow the examples and also logging a lot of info to try to reverse engineer it to work.
However even following all the information I could find I ended up with some weird state structure:

[image]

`scene` is a object containing the router state. However initial state is replicated inside `scene` (so it contains again `devices` and  `rooms` objects).

If I change the ordinary state devices or routes it throws an error as: `Key <name of the key> has already been defined` (other people reporting the same problems [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/376)).

So my question is: How do you route your react native apps with redux? Do you use other libraries? Are there any examples or documented resources I could use to fix my code?

Think that it has a typical redux structure. For the sake of the example, this is how it looks on my `app/index.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import reducers from './reducers'
import Home from './components/home'
import Device from './components/devices'
import Login from './components/login'

const middleware = [logger()]
const store = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)(createStore)(reducers)

const RouterWithRedux = connect(reducers)(Router)

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='login' component={Login} title='Login' />
            <Scene key='root' initial={true}>
            <Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home' />
            <Scene key='device' component={Device} title='Device' />
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It is actually my first sentence. I am trying to guess why my state looks like that

Comment: Please check out this link; https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/react-native-router-flux#reduxflux,  i followed this guide and i got redux routing http://i354.photobucket.com/albums/r416/TeNm/redux-routing_zpsvxwyigdw.png

Comment: @jsdario I am having a bit of trouble with react-native-router-flux with redux. Do you mind lending me a hand? Would really appreciate it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609148/reactjs-redux-how-to-connect-mapdispatchtoprops-to-a-component

Comment: seems you have removed it @JoKo

Comment: @jsdario Sorry, I was actually able to figure it out myself! Really appreciate you for checking it out though. I encountered one more issue and seems like another member is having the same problem. If you don't mind, could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611987/react-native-react-native-router-flux-how-to-apply-hidenavbar-to-only-one-sc/39614569#39614569 appreciate it again jsdario!

Comment: Just commented a work-around. Hope it works @joko

Comment: @jsdario Thank you jsdario! I'll give it a shot, and could you clarify on what you mean by `It is appropriate if your Login only appears once throughout your scene flow.`? Doesn't in that example only shown Login once since it is a stand alone scene? Also, I'll message the user who posted it to accept the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by my suffering experiences, there is no way to prevent `Router` re-render if you wrap it under a `Provider` and listen updates from `redux`, it is a nature by design.

the point how to prevent this, is: **`Router` should render once and just once**
it means:

If you didn't connect to redux at all, it works fine since your `Router` would not be triggered by any of updates from redux.

Also, you can `connect()` `Router` to `redux` to get a `dispatch()` method props but you can NOT listen to another props.

Thus, the architecture would be:

```
import {
    Router,
    Scene,
    Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';


// --- child component can connect and listen to props they want.
const myConnectedMainConponent = connect()(myMainConponent);
const myConnectedLoginConponent = connect()(myLoginConponent);

// --- Create it via Actions.create(), or it will be re-created for each render of your Router
const scenes = Actions.create(
    <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login" component={myLoginConponent} />
        <Scene key="main" component={myMainConponent} />
    </Scene>
);

// --- Create connected Router if you want dispatch() method.
// --- Or you can just use vanilla Router
const myConnectedRouter = connect()(Router);

// --- your exported main router
export default class MyExportedRouter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <myConnectedRouter scenes={scenes} />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

p.s. I typed above codes directly here, be aware the syntax error :)

**Point Taken:**

1. `Router` should render once and just once ( connect to get dispatch method only or not connect at all )
2. pre create scenes via Actions.create() and pass it into Router
3. move your app main logic into one of the children of Router

=====================

this is originally replied on https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/376#issuecomment-241965769

thanks @jsdario for mention here, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm using only `redux` and `react-redux`.
Creating a store with `createStore` with some middlewares (after doing `combineReducers`):

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, promiseMiddleware())),
);
```

Registering app:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MainComponent />
  </Provider>
));
```

Using state in components:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoading: state.core.isLoading,
});
```

Connecting component to state using `connect`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScene);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the routing side? Also it looks like you are connecting components to state one by one, rather than using the store. Am I wrong?

Comment: Routing? What do you mean here? Yeah, I'm connecting components rather than using store.

Comment: By routing I mean, as in the question body, that I am unable to connect redux with react-native-router-flux and so I was asking for alternatives. I'd still want to have a scenes API.

Answer (score 0):

You can now also use `NavigationExperimental` directly from react-native.

You can find more about it on this [link](http://blog.thebakery.io/react-native-experimental-navigation-with-redux/).

Comment: I am afraid we cannot support experimental features yet, for a production app.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's for everyone to decide on their own. My reasoning was it is included in react-native, so it will be developed and probably become a standard (also, it's actually one of react-native-router-flux-like libraries that was merged in). Maybe someone will investigate and think the way I think.