# React Native + react-native-router-flux: How to apply hideNavBar to only one <Scene/>?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs, react-native-router-flux

In React Native using react-native-router-flux, I have two `<Scene/>` and when I apply `hideNavBar` to the first one, `Login`, it also applies to the second, `Home` even though they are on the same level. How can I apply `hideNavBar` to only one `<Scene/>`, `Login`?

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene component={Login} hideNavBar initial={true} key='login' title='Login'/>
            <Scene component={Home} key='home' title='Home'/>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the reason. Probably it persists some state parameters accross diferent `actions/PUSH`. As a workaround, you can always try to be explicit: it worked for me.

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene component={Login} hideNavBar initial={true} key='login' title='Login'/>
            <Scene component={Home} hideNavBar={false} key='home' title='Home'/>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

From that route on, NavBar is visible. It is appropriate if your Login only appears once throughout your scene flow.